# Align navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have a problem concerning my navigation bar...

1. I want to position it to the center and its wont do it.
2. I want to to fill from the left to the right.

I tried to :
text-align: center in .navbar a
text-align: center in navbar.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: gray;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: lightgray;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="Guides.html">Guides</a>
  <a href="#">Clips</a>
  <a href="#">Leaderborard</a>
  <a href="Support the server.html">Support the server</a>
  <a href="Help.html">Help</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to look into CSS grid layout and/or Flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

I documented in the CSS source what I've done.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: gray;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  text-align: center; /* Added */
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  /* text-align: center; Removed */
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block; /* Changed from block */
  /* float: left; Removed */
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: lightgray;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
  <a href="Guides.html">Guides</a>
  <a href="#">Clips</a>
  <a href="#">Leaderborard</a>
  <a href="Support the server.html">Support the server</a>
  <a href="Help.html">Help</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work using

```
justify-content: center;
```

on a container

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.navbar {
  background-color: gray;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  text-align: center; /* Added */
}

.navbar a {
  color: white;
  /* text-align: center; Removed */
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block; /* Changed from block */
  /* float: left; Removed */
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: lightgray;
  color: orange;
}
.navbar1 {
      background-color: gray;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      top: 50%;
      text-align: center; /* Added */
    }
    
    .navbar1 a {
      color: white;
      /* text-align: center; Removed */
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding: 15px;
      display: inline-block; /* Changed from block */
      /* float: left; Removed */
    }
    
    .navbar1 a:hover {
      background: lightgray;
      color: orange;
    }
```

```html
   

 <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar">
        <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="Guides.html">Guides</a>
        <a href="#">Clips</a>
        <a href="#">Leaderborard</a>
        <a href="Support the server.html">Support the server</a>
        <a href="Help.html">Help</a>
      </div>
    </div>
<div class="navbar1">
            <a href="../index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="Guides.html">Guides</a>
            <a href="#">Clips</a>
            <a href="#">Leaderborard</a>
            <a href="Support the server.html">Support the server</a>
            <a href="Help.html">Help</a>
          </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks you for helping, your code works but i need one last thing. The sides are empty i want to fill it with the navigation bar...

Comment: Hi then just get rid of the container and apply the display: flex; justify-content: center; directly in the navbar class i have added a second version to the same snippet so you can compare the results

Comment: Wow ! It's work as i wanted thanks you for your help ! I already saw thoses tags, i need to see more about then.